# Error in Sidebar list while parsing JSON in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have a JSON file and want to parse the data in my sidebar with a format like
 If clicked button ("List all session")-->
 Shows all the sessions with location, something like
 SessionID1
   New York
   Washington
 SessionID2
   California.

The code

```
      for(var i = 0; i<data.sessions.length;i++){
       var locations = data.sessions[i].Location;
       if ('a' in locations) { 
       $(".ID1").append("New York");
    }
    if ('b' in locations) { 
    $(".ID1").append("Washington");
    }
    if ('c' in locations) { 
    $(".ID1").append("California");
    }

   sessionlist += "</ul></li>";
   $(".findsession-list").append(sessionlist);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google chrome is inidating that this is wrong:

```
var sessionlist += ('<li>' +  value.ID + '</li>');
```

Try replacing it with this:

```
var sessionlist += '<li>' +  value.ID + '</li>';
```

You should use better indentation in your code, that will help you find these kind of issues.

You will also need to declare `sessionlist` first, try this code:

```
var sessionlist = "";
for(var j = 0; j<data.sessions.length;j++){

    $.each(data.sessions, function(j, value) {
        sessionlist += '<li>' +  value.ID + '</li>';
    })
```

You might want to reset `sessionList` for each loop:

```
var sessionlist;
for(var j = 0; j<data.sessions.length;j++){
    sessionlist = "";

    $.each(data.sessions, function(j, value) {
        sessionlist += '<li>' +  value.ID + '</li>';
    })
```

You can replace this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<data.sessions.length;i++){
```

By:

```
 for(x in data){
```

And use `x`. Little neater

See http://jsfiddle.net/WsnDP/9/

Comment: That is because the HTML elements aren't visible. Thay are in hidden modal boxes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?